# How to embed html video without using youtube

Tags: html

Apparently I'm a total noob when it comes to web development. I just need help making a simple html file that embeds a video. I can't use youtube. I just need to embed the local file and it's not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="0" controls width="502" height="479">
        <source src="OWA tutorial.webm" type='video/webm'>
        <source src="OWA tutorial.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
        <p>Video is not visible, most likely your browser does not support HTML5 video</p>
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

This doesn't work. "OWA tutorial.mp4" is in the same folder as the html file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Who knows? Do you get errors? What happens?

Comment: As a suggestion, don't put space in your file names. Use hyphens instead.

Comment: What's "not working"?  Does the video not appear?  Not load?  Not play?

Comment: Also, HTML5 or XHTML. Pick one. You've got both right now.

Comment: The video module appears but the video doesn't play

Comment: @ceejayoz: XHTML5?  http://blog.whatwg.org/xhtml5-in-a-nutshell

Comment: @JohnDodson whats your browser

Comment: So those video files are in the same folder as your HTML document? If the path is not the problem, then check whether your webserver is delivering them with the correct `Content-Type` header - most browsers are picky about this.

Comment: @meda I'm using safari.

Comment: @CBroe So I need to be using a Web server? I had tried the apache server on the Mac OS and IIS on windows and neither worked. So I was hoping just opening an html file would work

Comment: @RocketHazmat XHTML5 was ditched. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/149839/is-xhtml5-dead-or-is-it-just-an-synonym-of-html5

Comment: @ceejayoz: Oh. RIP XHTML :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="0" width="502" height="479" controls> 
        <source src="loop.ogv" type="video/ogg">
        <p>Video is not visible, most likely your browser does not support HTML5 video</p>
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Worked well. Just replace the ogg with mp4, in your case.

Edit:
I'm not saying that you should use .ogv instead of .mp4.
I just used it as example because I've tried with a .ogv file (just because I don't have a .mp4 file here right now).
Your code should work if you copy mine and just replace the "loop.ogv" with your filename and the "video/ogg" with "video/mp4".
Sorry if it was misleading.

Comment: what is the loop.ogv file? And where do you have it?

Comment: So, what is your suggestion?  To use an `.ogv` file as well as `.webm` and `.mp4`?

Comment: The loop.ogv file is just a file that I had in my hand right now.
You should put your file there, whatever extension it is. 
I just suggest that you don't put white spaces in the filename.
Sorry if it wasn't clear.